# Can RxJava's scan operator keep state across multiple subscribers

Tags: java, rx-java

I have an observable, which is transformed with `scan` operator, so it always emits a value based on the current and the previous ones (or initial value).

```
Subject<String> subject = PublishSubject.create();
Observable<String> observable = subject.scan("zero", (a, b) -> a + ", " + b);
```

Then, first observer subscribes, prints all emitted values, and after some time unsubscribes.

```
Disposable first = observable.subscribe(System.out::println); // "zero"
subject.onNext("one"); // "zero, one"
first.dispose();
```

Later, another one subscriber subscribes:

```
Disposable second = observable.subscribe(System.out::println); // "zero"
subject.onNext("two"); // "zero, one"
second.dispose();
```

As you can see, each observer is first fed with the initial value and values emitted when the previous one was subscribed are gone. What I'd like to achieve is keeping the state inside `scan` operator across all subscriptions:

```
Disposable first = observable.subscribe(System.out::println); // "zero"
subject.onNext("one"); // "zero, one"
first.dispose();
Disposable second = observable.subscribe(System.out::println); // "zero, one"
subject.onNext("two"); // "zero, one, two"
second.dispose();
```

Is there a solution to this problem in RxJava?

Comment: You mean you want all subscribers to receive all the events from the beginning?

Comment: No, I want to receive only the events emitted when the subscriber is subscribed but I want this event's value to be based on all previous values.

Comment: Just multicast your Observable called 'observable' like in this example: http://blog.danlew.net/2016/06/13/multicasting-in-rxjava/. If you have concurrency, I would recommand to serialze the subjects onNext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution:

observable#publish will multicast the result to all subscriber and therefore persist the last #scan value. Your solution was not working, because you create a new Observable every time you subscribed to it. The scan value was not persisted.

```
@Test
void name3231() {
    Subject<String> subject = PublishSubject.create();
    Observable<String> observable = subject.scan("zero", (a, b) -> a + ", " + b);

    ConnectableObservable<String> observableMulticast = observable.publish();

    Disposable connect = observableMulticast.connect(); // must be disposed by hand

    TestObserver<String> test = observableMulticast.test();

    Disposable first = observableMulticast.subscribe(System.out::println); // "zero"
    subject.onNext("one"); // "zero, one"
    first.dispose();

    test.assertValues("zero, one");

    Disposable second = observableMulticast.subscribe(System.out::println); // "zero, one"
    subject.onNext("two"); // "zero, one, two"
    second.dispose();

    test.assertValues("zero, one", "zero, one, two");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution by introducing `BehaviorSubject` as a "caching" layer. Not sure if it is the cleanest way to solve the problem, but it works.

The line:

```
Observable<String> observable = subject.scan("zero", (a, b) -> a + ", " + b);
```

has to be transformed to:

```
Subject<String> observable = BehaviorSubject.create();
subject.scan("zero", (a, b) -> a + ", " + b)
       .subscribe(observable);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could scan into a `BehaviorSubject` and the others should subscribe to that:

```
Subject<String> subject = PublishSubject.create();
Observable<String> observable = subject.scan("zero", (a, b) -> a + ", " + b);
Subject<String> multicast = BehaviorSubject.create();

observable.subscribe(multicast);

Disposable first = multicast.subscribe(System.out::println); // "zero"
subject.onNext("one"); // "zero, one"
first.dispose();
Disposable second = multicast.subscribe(System.out::println); // "zero, one"
subject.onNext("two"); // "zero, one, two"
second.dispose();
```